# Android Studio Espresso BDD java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation Error

Tags: android, android-studio, ui-automation, android-espresso, cucumberjs

I have configured Android Studio4.0 Espresso BDD setup using Cucumber and Ghergin plugins.
I have properly written feature declaration and test definition classes.
also, I have added necessary dependencies and tags in build.gradle.
after synced all, when I tried to run my BDD feature class, am getting the following error same/continuously. I have tried clean, cache clear, invalid restart studio. it wont work.

Error Logs:

C:\Users\ALFA.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\info.cukes\cucumber-picocontainer\1.2.4\415ef48ddc2409272f383f2ea844cb821b657cf\cucumber-picocontainer-1.2.4.jar;
C:\Users\ALFA.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\junit\junit\4.12\2973d150c0dc1fefe998f834810d68f278ea58ec\junit-4.12.jar;
C:\Users\ALFA.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hamcrest\hamcrest-integration\1.3\5de0c73fef18917cd85d0ab70bb23818685e4dfd\hamcrest-integration-1.3.jar;

Skipped step

Skipped step

Skipped step

Skipped step

Skipped step

Failed scenarios:
C:/Users/ALFA/Desktop/Android UI BDD/Android_BDD_Espr_20Mar_2021/app/src/androidTest/assets/features/login.feature:14 # Scenario Outline: Input username and password

1 Scenarios (1 failed)
5 Steps (5 skipped)
0m0.004s

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation.
at androidx.test.InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.java:50)
at androidx.test.InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext(InstrumentationRegistry.java:101)
at androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule.(ActivityTestRule.java:144)
at androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule.(ActivityTestRule.java:120)
at androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule.(ActivityTestRule.java:103)
at com.example.myapplication.test.MainActivityTest.(MainActivityTest.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector.newInstance(AbstractInjector.java:145)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:342)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678)
at cucumber.runtime.java.picocontainer.PicoFactory.getInstance(PicoFactory.java:37)
at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:60)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHookIfTagsMatch(Runtime.java:223)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHooks(Runtime.java:211)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runBeforeHooks(Runtime.java:201)
at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:40)
at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenarioOutline.run(CucumberScenarioOutline.java:46)
at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:121)
at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:36)
at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
Process finished with exit code 1

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'

androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'info.cukes:cucumber-android:1.2.5@jar'
androidTestImplementation 'info.cukes:cucumber-picocontainer:1.2.4'

androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
```

package com.example.myapplication.test;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;

import cucumber.api.android.CucumberInstrumentationCore;

@CucumberOptions(
features = "features",
glue = "com.example.myapplication.test")

public class Instrumentation1 extends MonitoringInstrumentation {

```
private final CucumberInstrumentationCore instrumentationCore = new CucumberInstrumentationCore(this);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle arguments) {

    super.onCreate(arguments);

   // String tags = BuildConfig.TEST_TAGS;

    String tags = "";

    if (!tags.isEmpty()) {

        arguments.putString("tags", tags.replaceAll(",", "--").replaceAll("\\s",""));

    }

    instrumentationCore.create(arguments);

    start();

}

@Override
public void onStart() {

    super.onStart();

    waitForIdleSync();

    instrumentationCore.start();

}
```

### }

Feature: Login

Perform login on username and password are inputted

@login-feature
Scenario Outline: Input username and password

```
Given I have a login activity

When I input username <username>

And I input password "<password>"

And I press submit button

Then I should see on next activity

Examples:
  | username | password    |
  | covid19  | 123456789 |
```

Comment: did you resolved the issue?, if yes, could you please provide the solution..